# Multiple group mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose

Hello I want to use group functionality to group and count the category and subcategory.

Currently I am counting only the category but I need to count also the subcategory. In my case each category has many subcategories.

The categories and subcategories I am rendering it for the select option:

**Category example**

```
<select>
<option *ngFor="let x of countedCategory;">{{x._id}} {{x.countCategory}}</option>
</select>
```

**SubCategory example**

```
  <select>
    <option *ngFor="let x of countedCategory;">{{x.specCategory}} {{x.countSubCategory}}</option>
    </select>
```

My expected result should be like this:

```
    [
    {
    _id:'Water sports',
    specCategory: 'Snorkeling',
    countCategory:6,
    countSubCategory:2
    },
   _id:'Water sports',
    specCategory: 'Kite Surf',
    countCategory:6,
    countSubCategory:4
    }

    ]
```

**Mongoose Node.js**

```
   function getPriceBoundaries(filter, callback) {
        var query = {};
        var geoquery={};
        var gquery=[];

        ['city', 'category', 'specCategory', 'likelistSum',"specSpecCategory"].forEach(function (key) {
            if (filter[key]) {
                query[key] = filter[key];
            }
        });

        // is loc has in array remove city and add geoNear filter
        if(filter["loc"]){
            var near = filter.loc.$near;
            var geometry= near.$geometry;

           // console.log(filter["loc"],filter.loc.$near.$geometry,"query");
           geoquery= { near: { type: geometry.type, coordinates:geometry.coordinates }, minDistance: near.$minDistance,maxDistance: near.$maxDistance ,distanceField: "dist.calculated",spherical: true,num:100000000};
            delete  query["city"];
                gquery= [
                 {$geoNear:geoquery},
                 {$match: query},


                {
                    $group: {
                      _id:"$category",



                        min: {$min: '$price'},
                        max: {$max: '$price'},
                       total:{$sum:1}
                    }

                }


            ];


        }
        else{

                   delete  query["category"];
                   delete  query["loc"];
                   delete  query["specSpecCategory"];
                   delete  query["specCategory"];


                  gquery= [

                             {$match: query},

                            {
                                $group: {
                                    _id:null,
                                    min: {$min: '$price'},
                                    max: {$max: '$price'},
                                    total:{$sum:1}
                                }

                            }



                        ];


        }





        Experiences.aggregate(gquery, function (err, results) {



            callback(err, results || {min: 0, max: 0});
        });


    }
```

**Source Collection **Experiences****

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "category" : "Water sports",
    "specCategory": "Kite Surf",
    "price":"120"  
},
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "category" : "Water sports",
    "specCategory"; "Kite Surf",
    "price":"120"

},
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "category" : "Water sports",
    "specCategory"; "Snorkeling",
    "price":"100"

},
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "category" : "Water sports",
    "specCategory"; "Kite Surf",
    "price":"120"

},
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "category" : "Water sports",
    "specCategory"; "Snorkeling",
    "price":"90"

},
{
    "_id" : 6,
    "category" : "Water sports",
    "specCategory"; "Kite Surf",
    "price":"120"

}
```

Comment: It seems like someone who isn't actually sitting at your computer right now would need to actually know what the source data looks like in "addition" to your expected result. So we cannot really obtain a result without something of a source to obtain that from. Which means you really need to add that information to your question.

Comment: The question is how can I count multiple properties in a collection

Comment: I understand what you are asking. What I'm "telling you" is that noone can help you with that if you do not include the source data in the question. That message should be very clear. Nothing to work with means we cannot get to the result.

Comment: Ok I see. Check again please. I have a collections called Experiences.